# Present UIViewController in another one

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

There is iPad application with `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`.

I would like to show another `UIViewController` (clearColored with red UIView as a subview) with "blocking" `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar` from the tap.

How can I do it?

**EDITED**

if I use `[self presentViewController:aboutView animated:YES completion:nil];` :

[image]

it covers all with black background ((

Answer (score 1):

```
     [self.tabBarController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
     self.tabBarController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't want to hide them, I want my new viewController appear above them

Comment: @Romowski- you have said "blocking" UINavigationBar and UITabBar

Answer (score 0):

You can present a `UIViewController` which will obscure the underlying `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationBarController`. Try:

```
[self presentViewController:aViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Keep in mind that you will be responsible for dismissing this presented view controller by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` on the presenting view controller.

Comment: I don't need present it like modal, because in this case appears black background

Comment: Set the background as red? viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ViewController *detailview =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]
 [self.tabBarController presentViewController:detailview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't need present it like modal, because in this case appears black background

Comment: i checked this i did't get appears black background..in this case better you can set animation NO